# How to enqueue google fonts if we use directly in style.css

Tags: css

My theme has "selecting differrent google fonts options" So for that we need to load several .woff2 files. So i have added 2 type of woff2 files in Top of CSS file (Bitter & Lora). but i don't know How to change in funtions.php

Here is my Funtions.php font code:-

```
/**
 * Enqueue scripts and styles
 *
 * @since Cazuela 1.0
 */
function thsp_theme_scripts() {
    /*
     * Enqueue Google Fonts
     *
     * Check if fonts set in theme options require loading
     * of Google scripts
     */
    $theme_options = thsp_cbp_get_options_values();
    $theme_options_fields = thsp_cbp_get_fields();
    $body_font_value = $theme_options['body_font'];
    $heading_font_value = $theme_options['heading_font'];
    $body_font_options = $theme_options_fields['thsp_typography_section']['fields']['body_font']['control_args']['choices'];
    $heading_font_options = $theme_options_fields['thsp_typography_section']['fields']['heading_font']['control_args']['choices'];

    // Check if it's a Google Font
    if( isset( $body_font_options[$body_font_value]['google_font'] ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style(
            'font_' . $body_font_value,
            'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=' . $body_font_options[$body_font_value]['google_font']
        );
    }   
    // Check if it's a Google Font
    if( isset( $heading_font_options[$heading_font_value]['google_font'] ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style(
            'font_' . $heading_font_value,
            'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=' . $heading_font_options[$heading_font_value]['google_font']
        );
    }
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
```

Comment: Why do you need it directly in style.css?

Comment: For descresing page size... i will save more than 100kb size (if someone provide me correct code for function.php)  http://i.imgur.com/Zd7WY0e.jpg

Comment: Using `@import` method in your **CSS** to include fonts/stylesheet files won't make your page load speed faster, see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036977/best-way-to-include-css-why-use-import)

Comment: @Omar Soliman , I am not using @ Import method i am using directly woff2 file http://i.imgur.com/Zd7WY0e.jpg ... which is most important for page speed (i have already done on other website) but unable to understant in this theme.

Answer (score 0):

I have registered google fonts in my theme function file, then used it in style.css.

```
function register_google_fonts() {

  wp_register_style( 'googleFonts', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300');
  wp_enqueue_style( 'googleFonts');

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_google_fonts' );
```

style.css

```
.cssClass {

    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;

}
```

First, theme will try to load the Google font **Open Sans** if not then use the next font **sans-serif**